# show jira issues in bitbucket issue tracker

Tags: jira, bitbucket, jira-plugin

im trying to setup some projects in jira, we have existing bitbucket repos. Our jira projects have issues we have put in, is it possible to view these jira issues in bitbucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link JIRA to BitBucket by following this tutorial: [Linking Bitbucket and GitHub accounts to JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/linking-bitbucket-and-github-accounts-to-jira-300814271.html). This uses the JIRA DVCS Connector add-on which I believe is a free download from the Atlassian Marketplace.

Branches, pull requests and commit messages can reference JIRA issues. I'm not sure whether you can link existing branches etc though unless they reference the issue in JIRA directly.

Comment: Is Jira free to use with Bitbucket repo?

Comment: No, you purchase a JIRA license based upon the number of users that will need access to it. See https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira. Bitbucket does give some basic issue management though, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/issue-trackers-221449750.html